# How do I fix this text not showing up in bash output in Cmder?

Tags: bash, conemu, cmder

Before highlight:

[image]

After highlight:

[image]

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

ConEmu 161022 [64] Stable

I've messed around with the `Features -> Colors` panel a bit but haven't had any luck. How do I fix this?

Comment: You may use status bar to see the attributes of those hidden text. Just select one cell of it.

Comment: Where is this status bar? I can't find it in any of the menus or settings. I'm selecting that text and I don't see any values changing in the UI.

Comment: Status bar is on the usual place: https://conemu.github.io/en/StatusBar.html

Comment: Ah. that status bar is not there in Cmder. I'm using Cmder. The issue does not happen in ConEmu standalone.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Cmder. https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1346